# Why the glyphicon is not aligning with the rest of the elements in the same strip?

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I have 2 questions-

1. Apart from glyphicons, how can I add small icons in HTML/CSS? Is it not possible without bootstrap?
2. Why my home glyphicon not aligning vertically in the middle like the rest of the elements?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Here's the image]

Here's my HTML code-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="course_strip">
            <div class="course_strip_left">
                <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></p>
                <p>HTML</p>
                <p>CSS</p>
                <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
                <p>SQL</p>
                <p>PHP</p>
                <p>BOOTSTRAP</p>
                <p>JQUERY</p>
                <p>ANGULAR</p>
                <p>MORE</p>
            <div class="course_strip_right">
                <p>REFERENCES</p>
                <p>EXAMPLES</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS-

```
*{
     margin:0; 
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.course_strip{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height: 44px;
    color:#F1F1F1;
    line-height: 44px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
.course_strip p{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.course_strip p:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}
.course_strip p:active{
    background-color: green;
}
.course_strip_left p{
    float: left;
}
.course_strip_right p{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Word of warning: putting `box-sizing: border-box;` on the `*` selector _may cause unexpected problems_ in the future.

Comment: Hi Raj - if one of the answers below was "the answer" for you, it would be great if you would accept it!  I noticed in your account that you haven't accepted any answers - did you know you earn reputation when you accept an answer?  And the person who answered does as well.  It might be great for you to go through all your past questions and accept the answer(s) that helped you the most.  (You accept by clicking the big, gray checkmark below the number on the left side of the answer).

Comment: @cale_b Sorry I didn't knew about this feature, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You are welcome - and no need to be sorry! (And remember, you can still go through older questions you asked and accept them, too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to both your questions:

1. Besides Glyphicons, You can use other font-based icon libraries as well, such as [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/), or you can use images and embed them into your markup.  Font Awesome does *not* require a whole framework such as bootstrap (and actually, [neither does Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/))
2. The height issue with your icon is due to the line-height on your glyphicon is not the same as the rest of the elements. Use your browser's Inspector and you will see that you assign a line-height of 44px to everything in the strip, but glyphicon has a line-height of 1em.

Add a style to address the glyphicon in the strip, and you'll see it work.  (See below revised code).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.course_strip {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  height: 44px;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  line-height: 44px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}

.course_strip p {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.course_strip p:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.course_strip p:active {
  background-color: green;
}

.course_strip_left p {
  float: left;
}

.course_strip_right p {
  float: right;
}

/* Adjust line-height to your desired position */
.course_strip .glyphicon {
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tutorial</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="course_strip">
    <div class="course_strip_left">
      <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></p>
      <p>HTML</p>
      <p>CSS</p>
      <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
      <p>SQL</p>
      <p>PHP</p>
      <p>BOOTSTRAP</p>
      <p>JQUERY</p>
      <p>ANGULAR</p>
      <p>MORE</p>
      <div class="course_strip_right">
        <p>REFERENCES</p>
        <p>EXAMPLES</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks a ton @cale_b

Answer (score 2):

> .course_strip has line height of 44px. Set the same for icon.

```
.course_strip .course_strip_left p .glyphicon {line-height: 44px;}
```

Comment: I have removed the span and placed it in the p tag, still its not aligned.

Comment: My bad . I found it. It's the line height you're giving. give the same line height on the icon. @RajMalhotra

Comment: Now specific :D

Answer (score 0):

You can Add this CSS.

```
.course_strip >.course_strip_left > p > .glyphicon{
    float: right;
    padding: 10 10px;
}
```